# Custom UIAlertView with image

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I need to create a custom `UIAlertController` like the one shown in the image [image: Sample Alert]

Is it possible to create one, similar to the sample image?

Comment: batter option is just create one xib file that show your current view and when ever you need it just display it

Comment: you can create one custom view and present as alert

Answer (score 3):

Please consider to use custom implementation, like [this](https://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCAlertView).

Dealing with default UIAlertController's customization isn't the best idea.